# Looking to change the color underneath the skin

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, texture-painting, topology

so I've been making a character in Blender and long story short my topology is horrendous but has produced a really cool effect that I want to play with but don't know how.

Basically there are these white lines *underneath* the skin which I painted on using vertex paint and the node editor. Here's a photo.[image: CHARACTER]

They appeared when, in vertex paint, I began using the blend brush. I think basically the blur brush brought these white lines out on my horrendous topology and highlighted the seams, bringing out some glowing white material underneath that I don't know how to edit.

My question is this:

How do I change the color of these lines?

I want to change them to a red color or possibly a blue or purple so they look like alien markings but cannot for the life of me figure out how to.

If you need any more information please let me know. Hope to hear from you soon!

Here is the link to the file.

[image]

- Andrew.

Comment: Since it seems to depend on your specific topology, maybe you should share it (if you feel so, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  then edit your question and paste the provided link)

Comment: you'll have to excuse the topology. I've been learning as I go how important it is and how to better manage it. I'm very new to this. This is pretty much the first game character I've tried to develop and it's more of a learning experience than something permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/bake.html), and then edit them outside blender (for example with Gimp).
The vertex paint can replaced using dynamic paint.

You can bake the vertex colors at the render panel. There, you will find the bake mode "Vertex Colors" which will export the vertex painting.

In your image editing software, you can change the hue or brightness or whatever and after image processing, you can bring it back as a texture.

As for applying the modified vertex paint to your model, the following QA will be helpful.
[How to bake uv map texture to vertex color (selected to active)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26503/how-to-bake-uv-map-texture-to-vertex-color-selected-to-active)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, imho it could be difficult to "control" this "effect" since it is applied on, as you say, a wrong topology: but how bad is it? Using the 3d print toolbox addon, this bad:

[image]

That said, you are mixing (multiplying) the vertex colors and a color ramp, so you can, at least, act on

- vertex colors
- colorramp colors and settings
- mixing properties (mode, amount)

This is the current setup:

[image]

If you just change the color of the selected point of the colorramp to something very different than white:

[image]

but if you change the mixing factor amount:

[image]

then, if you also change the mixing mode:

[image]

Then you could change other materials setting, add more nodes and mixing modes, but to have a full "control" of the result, I would first remove unpredictable factors like (so much) bad geometry because tools are thought to be used with good geometry, not whatever you come up with...

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers now but I think none of them describes what you basically wanted to do: change the color. There are 2 solutions for this. The first being drawing your vertex color with red or something. The second is the one I prefer. Add a color mix node in between your vertex color node and the other color mix node and set its blending method to Multiply so you have first your vertex color input. Going in to a color mix node with blending method multiply. That node should have a Fac value of 1 and the second color is the color your want your pattern to be. The output of that node goes into the input of the next mix node where you currently have your vertex colors attached to.